# Print "--more--" and wait for spacebar press to continue

Tags: python, terminology

What is the term in Python for waiting to print until the user presses the spacebar, displaying `--more--` until that point, like this?

[image: screenshot of Python help waiting for spacebar press]

Comment: There is no single function that does this, although you could easily write one. The main challenge is knowing the page size (i.e. after how many lines to wait for a keystroke). Instead of doing this yourself in Python, it may make a lot more sense to do it from the command line, i.e. `python my_script.py | more`. What problem are you solving exactly?

Comment: @Grismar I'm making a text-based game, but the intro text just looks like a wall of text. I'm trying to think of some way to make it more dramatic. What exactly does `python my_script.py | more` do?

Comment: I think what would suit you well is the curses library https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Oh and my_script.py | more will pipe the output of python to the more program ie connect the standard output of the my_script.py program to the standard input of the more program. This is not what you want.

Comment: @DavidOldford Thanks! I'll check it out. What on Earth is the "more" program, though?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "pager".  You can implement one yourself, or use one of the Python pager libraries, like the aptly named [pager](https://pypi.org/project/pager/)

Comment: @AnonCoward Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead. I would upvote :)

Comment: @AnonCoward You could add the Wikipedia link too: [terminal pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager)